# Extract unix compatible filepath with space from command output

Tags: shell, text-processing

the command :

```
du -sh $HOME/* | grep '[0-9]G\>' | sort -k 1rn | head -1
```

is giving me :

```
41G     /Users/user/Big folder
```

How can i extract the path to reuse it in my script ?

```
du -sh $HOME/* | grep '[0-9]G\>' | sort -k 1rn | head -1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Will output

```
/Users/user/Big
```

Which is unusable, where i am looking for a result like :

```
/Users/user/Big\ folder
```

Comment: Just replace your `awk` part with `awk -v q="'" '{ print q$2q }'`

Comment: My bad, just edited my post :

`du -sh $HOME/* | grep '[0-9]G\>' | sort -k 1rn | head -1 | awk '{ print $2 }'`

Gives 

`/Users/user/Big`

Comment: So
`awk -v q="'" '{ print q$2q }'`
will give
`'/Users/user/Big'`
but we are almost there...!

Comment: I suspect this is an XY problem and the real answer is "quote your shell variables"

Comment: There's no variables declared involved at that point, i was thinking of something implying storing in a variable but not sure how to do so.

Comment: Use `du -sh $HOME/* | grep '[0-9]G\>' | sort -k 1rn | head -1 | cut -f2`

Comment: This gives 
`/Users/user/Big folder`

Maybe there is a way to convert this in 

`/Users/user/Big\ folder``

Or just found the magic trick to add "\ " before each space then...

Comment: If there are "no variables involved" how do you know it is "unusable"?

Comment: @steeldriver if the output is `Users/user/Big folder` and i inject it in $VAR i guess that `cd $VAR` won't work ?

Comment: . . . but `cd "$VAR"` will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSIXLY:

```
du -s "$HOME"/* | sort -rnk1 | LC_ALL=C sed -e "s,[^/]*\(/.*\),'\1',;q"
```

Without `-h`, `du` result included plain number for size, so we can easily sort it without extra `grep`.

Using `sed` to perform deletion at the first line only then quitting, we save a `head` invocation.

Comment: output is `'/Users/user/Big folder'`, but still missing the "\ " to have `'/Users/user/Big\ folder'`

Comment: @VinhFrancisGuyait The result is quoted, so the same as escaping the whitespace?

Comment: Not escaping it, the idea at the end is to use the output with other command like for treatment in the script.

Comment: @VinhFrancisGuyait So `for f in '/Users/user/Big folder' ...` just work as you want.

Comment: true, didn't realized ! Thanks @cuonglm

Answer (score 1):

When doing automated processing, don't make your life more complicated by using numbers in different units. Don't pass `-h` to `du`. Then you can use simple numerical sorting on the output, and your script will still work if you have more than 1 TB in one of the directories.

```
du -s ~/* | sort -k 1n | tail -n1
```

This always prints out a line, even if the largest subdirectory contains less than 1 GB. If that's not what you want, you can replace the conditional “is the output empty” by “is the number less than the threshold”.

To extract the directory name, take the output and remove the part up to the first tab.

```
largest_directory=$(du -s ~/* | sort -k 1n | tail -n1)
largest_directory_size_kB=${largest_directory%%$(printf '\t')*}  # if you need the size
largest_directory=${largest_directory#*$(printf '\t')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to extract the path you want is via `read` command after you're done doing the `du` stuff and `sort-ed` them and then pass on to the `while/read`

```
du.. sort.. | while read x d; do echo "$d"; done
```